# What do I need in order to write assembly on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, assembly

I would like to program in asm on my Windows 7 computer.

I have some knowledge about asm.

I would like to know the tools I need to use and also how to program the graphics side (in order to create a video game).

Comment: Hi Shinobi, I'm not sure ASM is a great place to start your programming journey, but it could well be a stop along the way.  Maybe search for a game writing engine on the internet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines and start with a language like python or basic.  Good luck

Comment: code in C first so you will get familiar with the basics of Windows API. Once you be familiar with it, just go with assembler...

Answer (score 15):

[FASM (aka FlatAsembler)](http://flatassembler.net) - it contains everything you need to program in assembly language for Windows or Linux, including a lightweight IDE.

[Fresh IDE](http://fresh.flatassembler.net) - It is the same as FASM but with advanced IDE for visual and RAD development.

Each of these two packages are self-sufficient and there is documentation and examples inside.

Maybe the only other tool you need is a good debugger: [Olly debugger](http://www.ollydbg.de/) is the best for Windows. And as long as there is no debugger of comparable quality for any other OS then it is the best user mode debugger in the world. :)

About the graphics and game programming - go to the [FASM message board](http://board.flatassembler.net), there is a lot of discussions on this subject, sources and friendly community to help you

**Important Note 1** - I am a little bit biased, Fresh IDE is my project, but I started it because FASM is really the best assembler ever made and it deserves good RAD IDE.

**Important Note 2** - There is another good assembler - NASM - but it is not so good for beginners or fully assembly written projects.

Comment: The template.exe file output by the default Console project of Fresh IDE is detected as a virus by Avira. Here is the exact message: Virus or unwanted program 'HEUR/APC (Cloud) [HEUR/APC]' detected.

Comment: @Benny - it is false positive. It is known problem with assembly language programs. Some of the AV heuristics simply can't recognize the code pattern. The only way I know is to report the problem to the AV maker.

Comment: I just found this, which looks very nice.  http://www.easycode.cat/English/index.htm